# Zorba XQuery Update Facility direct modification XML Files

Tags: java, file, xquery, zorba

does anybody know if there is a simple option or switch 
to modify XML Files directly using the Command Line interface of the zorba java implementation.

In Saxon EE there is a "-update:on" parameter, 
in BaseX "declare option db:writeback 'true';" turns the immediate update facility on.

I spend a lot time searching to get information  about writing directly to the files.

The only reason I stick to zorba is the scripting facility and the documentation of the functions and extension that make it more productive.

Kind regards,

Josh

Comment: I don't think there is one. You will have to do it similar to here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18237516/update-multiple-xml-files-using-xquery-and-zorba

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly modify the XML files. The updates can not be persistently stored. However, there is a workaround.

An example is as follows:
`for $doc in doc("auction.xml")/site/open_auctions//bidder/increase
return insert node <watch open_auction="open_auction5104"/> before $doc;
doc("auction.xml")`

You can redirect the output. 
`zorba queryfile.xq > someFile.xml`